# Cascaded join using mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB using **Node Js**. I have three schemas: Projects, Users, and Teams.
I need to retrieve the **project details** based on it's `type` with the **worker users**.
I got stuck in making **join** for these schemas:

Projects:

```js
const Project = new Schema({
    projectName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    teamID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
});
```

Teams

```js
const Team = new Schema({
    teamId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, trim: true },
    users: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], required: true, trim: true },
    teamName: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Users:

```js
const User = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, trim: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    profilePicture: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});
```

I am trying to find a way to get

```
[
   {
      projectName: "s",
      type: "w",
      users: ["Jon", "Ali", "Mark"]
   },
   {
      projectName: "a",
      type: "w",
      users: ["Jon", "Mark"]
   },   {
      projectName: "s",
      type: "w",
      users: ["Jon", "Ali", "Mark"]
   },
]
```

I tried to use `$lookup`, but I can not use it because the relation is complex many to many relations.
**Is there a way more efficient than retrieving all users, all teams, and all projects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no other efficient way except aggregation and without lookup we can't join collections, You can use nested lookup,

- `$match` condition for `type`
- `$lookup` to join Team collection using `teamID`
- `$match` teamID
- `$lookup` to join User collection using `users` array
- `$project` to convert user's name array using `$map`
- `$addFields` to get users array in users using `$arrayElemAt`

```
db.Project.aggregate([
  { $match: { type: "w" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Team",
      let: { teamID: "$teamID" },
      as: "users",
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$teamID", "$teamId"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "User",
            localField: "users",
            foreignField: "userId",
            as: "users"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            users: {
              $map: {
                input: "$users",
                in: "$$this.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { users: { $arrayElemAt: ["$users.users", 0] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wpd1WzJ_pov)

---

Second possible way, you can combine `$project` and `$addFields` stages in single stage,

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      users: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$users.users",
              in: "$$this.name"
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J84oEEFj1Ku)